# Create new user with more attribute in asmack

Tags: smack, asmack

I am trying to create new user with more attribute but it is not working.I am using this code with asmack:

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("SERVER IP", 5222,"localhost");
config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
XMPPConnection conn2 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
conn2.connect();
AccountManager manager =AccountManager.getInstance(conn2);
Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
attributes.put("username", "my_user_name");
attributes.put("password", "my_password");
attributes.put("email", "foo@foo.com");
attributes.put("name", "my_full_name");
manager.createAccount("my_user_name", "my_password", attributes);
conn2.login("my_user_name", "my_password");
ChatManager chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(conn2);
Log.w("User Name:",""+manager.getAccountAttribute("name"));
```

But when I try to log with `getAccountAttribute` all fields are returning null except username and password.

How can I set name,email etc. fields in asmack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that with VCard.

1. To save VCard:

   ```
   VCard vCard = new VCard();
   vCard.setFirstName("foo");
   vCard.setEmailHome("foo@foo.com");
   vCard.save(conn2);
   ```
2. To load VCard:

   ```
   VCard vCard = new VCard();
   vCard.load(conn2);
   String name = vCard.getFirstName();
   ```

**Note: You have to login first to save VCard.**

Comment: Do you know how can i access this data from ejanberd module ? (Erlang)

Comment: I need to save android device token.Which field is good for me ?

Comment: @Okay I believe you can use `vCard.setField("Token", Value)` and retrieve by `vCard.getField("Token")` .